# Cannot add dynamic height to element with tailwind in react/next

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have this element

```
<div className="relative w-8 h-24 bg-[#edeef0]">
  <div className={`absolute bottom-0 w-full h-[${Math.round((value.rank / 32) * 100)}%] bg-[#008E97]`}>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Math.round function returns a value between 0-100 and I have checked in dev tools that the class name being passed is correct. Example: h-[43%] or h-[32%]. However, the height attribute is not being applied to the element. If I hardcode in the height, like h-[54%], it works correctly. Does anyone know why this is not working?

[image: HTML in Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: You cannot construct class name dynamically with tailwindcss https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names I would recommend you to use `style` attribute